XSLT Transformation Error in XML Copy Editor
I'm experiencing issues performing an XSLT transformation in XML Copy Editor and hope someone can help diagnose what I'm doing wrong. Here are the details:
Environment

Editor: XML Copy Editor
Operating System: Windows 11

When attempting to apply an XSLT transformation to an XML file, I receive two primary errors:
Error in transformacion.xslt:

Message: "Error at line 2, column 80: no declaration found for element 'xsl:stylesheet'"

This error suggests there might be a syntax issue or an unrecognized element in my XSLT file. However, the syntax appears to be correct.
Error in artistasej.xml:

Message: "Error at line 4, column 11: no declaration found for element 'artistas'"

This error indicates that the editor is expecting some declaration for the artistas element, possibly a DTD or Schema, but none is intended or provided.
transformacion.xslt code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Tabla de artistas</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Código</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Año de nacimiento</th>
            <th>Año de fallecimiento</th>
            <th>País</th>
            <th>Página web</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="artistas/artista[nacimiento > 1500]">
            <xsl:sort select="nacimiento" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <tr>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="@cod"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="nombreCompleto"/></td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="nacimiento"/></td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="fallecimiento">
                            <xsl:value-of select="fallecimiento"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>Desconocido</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </td>
                <td><xsl:value-of select="pais"/></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{fichaCompleta}" target="_blank">Saber más</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>´´


artistasej.xml code

´´<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transformacion.xslt"?>
<artistas>
    <artista cod="a101">
        <nombreCompleto>Diego Velázquez</nombreCompleto>
        <nacimiento>1599</nacimiento>
        <fallecimiento>1660</fallecimiento>
        <pais>España</pais>
        <fichaCompleta>https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Vel%C3%A1zquez</fichaCompleta>
    </artista>
    <!-- Additional artist elements -->
</artistas>´´


I have verified that there are no extra spaces or syntax errors in the XSLT file. Also, I have made sure that there is no DOCTYPE or schema linked to the XML file that could trigger validation issues.And I have tried disabling validation in XML Copy Editor but haven't found an option to do so.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what might be causing these errors and how to resolve them. Thank you in advance!


Sorry, I added the quotation marks "´´'" to "



Diego Velázquez.
        1599
1660.
        Spain.
        https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diego_Vel%C3%A1zquez


"by mistake when posting this question, in case you tell me that's the error.
Well, what do you want us to do, provide you a schema for XSLT? The XSLT 2 and 3 specs have one. But does that error or warning in your editor prevent you from running the XSLT? Perhaps ask the support of that XML copy editor software for help on how to use that software. Your stylesheet works fine.

I don't know the "XML Copy Editor" of which you speak, but it looks as if you have some setting enabled to attempt validation against a schema or DTD, which is inappropriate when the document doesn't have one - in particular, for XSLT stylesheets.
